What type of wood is this? Is it worth refinishing in 1920 farmhouse?
We are working on renovations and there are two separate sections of wood (used to be two rooms until 1950~) one side clearly has stained wood that was used as a floor, the other looks either unstained or unstained in a very long time. We would love some help identifying the types of wood & if they were meant to be the subfloor or the original hardwoods that just got covered up! The black wood is the divider between the original rooms and the holes are for knob and tube wiring. The blue sheetrock is a vent cover for the old oil boiler that used to be in the house.
The black stuff is not asbestos, that's been covered already! Pretty sure its tar paper
Thanks!




it depends on your budget. refinishing is more work, but it will cost you less than replacing

Thanks! We plan on refinishing them! Just trying to make sure were not refinishing a subfloor haha

In very old houses, sometimes there is only one layer of flooring, i.e. your tongue and groove flooring sits directly on the floor joists. If you aren't sure if it's subfloor, either try to find the way your joists run.. they will run perpendicular if it's sub floor, look underneath, or find a place to measure the thickness to the cavity below. You should also be able to see through those holes in the floor as well.

Based on grain density it is not some hardwood

Even if sub floor, if nice looking wood, I would go for it.  It will depend on the thickness of the wood, since heavy duty sanding might be needed.  1/2 inch wood might not take sanding too much and be safe.  3/4 to an inch will be better.  The bif floor sanders will need to be careful, on softwood they can sand though to the basement in no time.

It's tough to identify wood from a picture, but it sure looks like vertical grain (i.e. quartersawn) Douglas Fir to me.  It could also be a similar wood such as hemlock.  Douglas fir was a fairly common flooring material in those days, especially in the western US.
